# Print the first N lines of a CSV where quoted fields can contain newlines

Tags: shell, csv, awk, sed

CSV file can have data with new line . it can be with any column. Also some line can have data without any new line so it should work in all case

Sample input

```
   ID,username,mobile,city,Message,Address,city
'11111111',TestUSer,1234567890,test,"Hi how are you? Well: we will connnect

Thanks for your time!
With Joy.
Test",Address test,City test
11111116,TestUser,1234567891,test,hello msg,Address test1,City test1
'111111167',TestUSer,1234567890,test,"Hi how are you one? Well: we will connnect

Thanks for your time!
With Joy.
Test",Address test,City test
11111112,TestUser,1234567891,test1,hello msg1,Address test2,City test2
11111113,TestUser,1234567891,test1,hello msg1,Address test2,City test2
11111114,TestUser,1234567891,test1,hello msg1,Address test2,City test2
```

I am using below command to read top 5 record of csv

```
awk -v RS='("[^"]*")?\r?\n' 'NF{ORS = gensub(/\r?\n(.)/, "\\\\n\\1", "g", RT);  ++n; print} n==5{exit}' file.csv
```

Actual output:

```
ID,username,mobile,city,Message,Address,city
'11111111',TestUSer,1234567890,test,"Hi how are you? Well: we will connnect\nThanks for your time!\nWith Joy.\Test",Address test,City test
11111116,TestUser,1234567891,test,hello msg,Address test1,City test1
'111111167',TestUSer,1234567890,test,"Hi how are you one? Well: we will connnect\nThanks for your time!\nWith Joy.\nTest",Address test,City test
11111112,TestUser,1234567891,test1,hello msg1,Address test2,City test2
11111113,TestUser,1234567891,test1,hello msg1,Address test2,City test2
11111114,TestUser,1234567891,test1,hello msg1,Address test2,City test2
```

Wanted output:

```
ID,username,mobile,city,Message,Address,city
'11111111',TestUSer,1234567890,test,"Hi how are you? Well: we will connnect\nThanks for your time!\nWith Joy.\Test",Address test,City test
11111116,TestUser,1234567891,test,hello msg,Address test1,City test1
'111111167',TestUSer,1234567890,test,"Hi how are you one? Well: we will connnect\nThanks for your time!\nWith Joy.\nTest",Address test,City test
11111112,TestUser,1234567891,test1,hello msg1,Address test2,City test2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your shown samples only, could you please try following `awk` code. Written and tested with GNU `awk`. Make use of `RS` record separator and then substitute globally to nullify new lines in RT, then print the lines accordingly.

```
awk -v RS='"[^"]*"' '{gsub(/\n/,"\\n",RT);ORS=RT} 1' Input_file
```

To get first 10 records, try following:

```
awk -v RS='"[^"]*"' '{gsub(/\n/,"\\n",RT);ORS=RT} 1' Input_file | head -10
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning: Self promotion ahead!

I wrote an `awk`-like utility called [`tawk`](https://github.com/shawnw/tawk) that uses tcl as its scripting language, and has a mode that reads CSV data without having to hack around with regular expressions to handle records with embedded newlines and quotes (This feature was actually my major inspiration for it).

Using it:

```sh
$ tawk -csv 'line {$NR <= 5} { puts [regsub -all {\n+} $F(0) "\\n"]; if {$NR == 5} exit }' input.csv
ID,username,mobile,city,Message,Address,city
'11111111',TestUSer,1234567890,test,"Hi how are you? Well: we will connnect\nThanks for your time!\nWith Joy.\nTest",Address test,City test
11111116,TestUser,1234567891,test,hello msg,Address test1,City test1
'111111167',TestUSer,1234567890,test,"Hi how are you one? Well: we will connnect\nThanks for your time!\nWith Joy.\nTest",Address test,City test
11111112,TestUser,1234567891,test1,hello msg1,Address test2,City test2
```